# array.find returning multiple results

Tags: javascript, arrays, ejs

I am trying to compare a single result to an array of items (Api to be specific). Instead of `.find()` to return the *first* result it matches with the `Details.title`, it returns *all* the result. I am using EJS:

```
<% 
Movies.find(element => {
    if(Details.title === element.text){
        console.log(element)
    }
})
%>
```

`Movies` there is the Array of items (the api). I looped over `Movies` trying to get a single result that matches with `Details.title`, but it gives me all the results that match.

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Though I do not have experience on EJS, `Array.find` needs to return true on match. I do not see any return value in your code

Comment: Is it really _returning_ the results or is it just console logging everything?  What does this do for you?  `<%Movies.find(element => Details.title === element.text)%>`

Comment: @jmargolisvt yes it logs everything out

Comment: I realize that.  I'm trying to get you to see that your current code is just producing a side effect and not using `find` correctly because you have no return value.

Comment: @jmargolisvt i just tried the return statement but it didn't return any output

Answer (score 3):

You are not really using `find` as it should be.

The way you use it is not different than you would do with `forEach`: you decide with an `if` what you will output within the callback and don't indicate anything to stop the iteration: so you get an output of all matches.

Instead you should return a truthy value in the callback when you have a match, and not output anything there. The output should be based on what `find` *returns*:

```
console.log(Movies.find(element => Details.title === element.text));
```

Notice especially the position of `console.log`: it takes as argument what `find` returns.

Compare the difference in these runnable snippets:

#### Bad:

```js
let Movies = [
    { text: "Arena", year: 1989 },
    { text: "Arena", year: 2011 },
    { text: "Asylum", year: 1972 },
    { text: "Asylum", year: 2005 },
];
let Details = { title: "Asylum" };

Movies.find(element => {
    if (Details.title === element.text) {
        console.log(element);
    }
});
```

#### Good:

```js
let Movies = [
    { text: "Arena", year: 1989 },
    { text: "Arena", year: 2011 },
    { text: "Asylum", year: 1972 },
    { text: "Asylum", year: 2005 },
];
let Details = { title: "Asylum" };

console.log(Movies.find(element => Details.title === element.text));
```

Comment: please am still confused could you write a little code to explain thanks...

Comment: I added two snippets. One with your code, and one with mine -- both using the same data.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you don't return true when you find your item. The find function will keep going if not *truthy* value.

This will never know you "found" what you wanted.

```js
Movies.find(element => {
    if(Details.title === element.text){
        console.log(element)
    }
})
```

This will know it should stop because you told it that you found what you wanted by returning true.

```js
Movies.find(element => {
    if(Details.title === element.text){
        console.log(element)
         return true
    }
})
```

Since we know that if true is returned the item is returned we can directly return the result of the comparison which is either true or false (exactly what we want)

```js
Movies.find(element => {
      return Details.title === element.text
})
```

As a last step, we could o use some syntactical sugar that comes with arrow functions.

```js
Movies.find(element => Details.title === element.text)
```